# Groovy to get values from xlsx with Apache POI

Tags: groovy, apache-poi, soapui, xlsx, apache-commons

I try to read values from a xlsx file to properties in SoapUI 5.4.0.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.*;

class ExcelReader {

  def readData() {
        def path = "C:\\docs\\data.xlsx";
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        rowIterator.next()
        Row row;                       
        def rowsData = []
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
             row = rowIterator.next()
             def rowIndex = row.getRowNum()
             def colIndex;
             def rowData = []
             for (Cell cell : row) {
                 colIndex = cell.getColumnIndex()
                  rowData[colIndex] = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
             }                    
             rowsData << rowData
         }
         rowsData
  }
 }

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def myTestCase = context.testCase

ExcelReader excelReader = new ExcelReader();
List rows = excelReader.readData();
def d = []
Iterator i = rows.iterator();
while( i.hasNext()){
         d = i.next();
         myTestCase.setPropertyValue("From", d[0])
         myTestCase.setPropertyValue("To", d[1])       
         testRunner.runTestStepByName( "ConversionRate")

}
```

I copied following dependency jar files to `/bin/ext` folder in SoapUI root:

```
commons-collections4-4.2-javadoc.jar
commons-collections4-4.2.jar
commons-compress-1.18.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
poi-4.0.1.jar
poi-examples-4.0.1.jar
poi-excelant-4.0.1.jar
poi-ooxml-4.0.1.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-4.0.1.jar
poi-scratchpad-4.0.1.jar
xmlbeans-3.0.2.jar
```

I got error message when script is executed:

> org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException:
>   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
>   error at line: 39

Line 39: `List rows = excelReader.readData();`

Comment: [org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:66)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLFactory.java?view=markup#l66) throws that kind of error. I suspect it is a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;`. But that method is in `XmlOptions` which is in `xmlbeans-3.0.2.jar`. So where have you got the `xmlbeans-3.0.2.jar` from? Is it  the correct one? Or are there other `jar`s in classpath also exporting `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions`?

Comment: @AxelRichter : No, I added it after I got error message. I got all the jars from https://mvnrepository.com/.

Comment: Can you get the complete stack trace of the exception somewhere? Maybe there are error logs? The `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` only was a suspicion from me.

Comment: @AxelRichter : I haven't got anything else, log output is clear.

Comment: Then you are lost. There must be a complete stack trace of the exception somewhere. But as so often, tools that users should support hinder users instead, because they suppress error messages. Maybe some `groovy` or `soapui` expert can tell you how to get the complete stack trace of the exception. I am not such an expert.

Answer (score 1):

My Advice is - take advantage of Fillo jar available and connect to XLS to fetch data.
[Fillo jar](https://codoid.com/fillo/)

Following imports are needed:

```
import com.codoid.products.exception.FilloException;
import com.codoid.products.fillo.Connection;
import com.codoid.products.fillo.Fillo;
import com.codoid.products.fillo.Recordset;
```

Comment: It seems ok. I added imports to your answer.